# Is it possible to use two different internet connection for different applications in windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, internet

My computer has two ethernet adapters and I have two internet connections which have their respective routers connected to those ethernet ports on the PC.

Is it possible to use them both at the same time for mutually exclusive tasks?

for ex, using one connection for downloading torrents while using the other one for surfing web via a browser?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is rather difficult since routing is destination-IP-based, not source-program-based. I've played with a similar setup, and IMO it's not worth it. But you can kinda get there by using WinGate to bind a SOCKS proxy (TCP-only) to a specific interface and telling one application to use that proxy.

Comment: Connectify has a load-balancer which works fine to accomplish what you want. Check out: [http://www-usw3.connectify.me/dispatch/](http://www-usw3.connectify.me/dispatch/)

Comment: @Cown IIRC Connectify et al. spread the load more-or-less evenly (by connection, not by traffic) but can't bind a specific application to a specific interface. More, it doesn't cope particularly well with heavily disparate networks - e.g. if you want to upload a video and one network has 10x the upstream bandwidth of the other one, Connectify might use the 'wrong' network for the upload.

Comment: @Bob roger that! :-)